# Восстановление пароля GPG

Tags: gpg

Всех приветствую.

Недавно у меня случилась беда. Я забыл GPG пароль от бекапов на сервере. Я имею бекап ключа в формате .asc, а так же, установленный ключ на сервере.

Как восстановить пароль?

Comment: Может быть, это поможет? https://stackru.com/questions/56433528/vosstanovit-uteryannyij-parol-gpg

Comment: Увы, не помогло...